# Apache - getting "Forbidden" only from some locations

Tags: apache-2.4

My website is http://self.hellobox.co.

For some strange reasons, some users are getting "Forbidden" Apache error. It works fine on my end.

So I went to this site "http://www.locabrowser.com" - which allows me to take screenshots from different locations around the world.

Funnily enough, it looks like from Japan and Israel users get this error, but from some other locations the site load fine. [screenshot attached below]

[image]

I don't have any IP-address specific "deny" rules at all on my Apache config file or my .htaccess file.

I tried to look at my error.log file, but when this error happens, nothing gets logged.

I also looked at my IPTABLES rules, but there are no IP-address specific rules.

I do have "fail2ban" enabled. Is there something I should check in that?

Are there any other things I can check to get this working?

FYI, I DID have IP-address specific block in my htaccess file a long time ago, but they are not there now. There can't be any "caches" of those things right?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT** : ok I found the following line from the error.log file

> [authz_core:error] [pid 25724] [client 203.29.159.134:52087] AH01630:
>   client denied by server configuration:

I googled and did what I could to resolve, but without any luck.

**EDIT2** : I've been testing my site with "browserling.com" and it turns out that whenever the user's IP address is IPv6 I'm getting the "forbidden" error. IPv4 works fine.

Now how do I get around this?

Comment: What does the log say about these requests?

Comment: Are you perhaps relying on being able to do a reverse DNS lookup? It would be best to see a (sanitised) version of your configuration. You may find my https://github.com/cameronkerrnz/scriptorium/blob/master/httpd-dump-config to be useful to serialise your configuration file (I've not tested it on Ubuntu though)

Comment: Do you have the IPv6 address go to the same virtual host? It wouldn't be the first time that using IPv6 to access a webserver instead of IPv4 gives an error because there is no virtualhost config for the IPv6 address.